# Android making a call with a predefined call duration

Tags: android, sms, call

I am building an Android application that will automatically make calls and send SMSes to some telephone numbers.

The problem is I need to specify the duration (how long the call will last for) of all the calls.

Is there any way to specify the call duration from Java code? Or how do I cut the present outgoing call?

Answer (score 2):

You may work on Java Runnables and then merge it with call and telephony API.